# Difference between Access Point / Station and Bridge / Router?

Tags: networking, routes, router, access-point

In my current network setup, I have a Cisco RVS4000 router that feeds into a 48 port ethernet switch and a Ubiquiti PicoStation M2 wireless access point.

I want the Cisco router to act as a DHCP server for the whole network. I am unsure how I should setup the Ubiquiti PicoStation M2...

The 2 options which seem relevant are **Network Mode** and **Wireless Mode**.

The options for **Network Mode** are:

- Bridge
- Router
- SOHO Router

The options for **Wireless Mode** are:

- Station
- Station WDS
- Access Point
- Access Point WDS

From what I've read and what I want... I'd go for **Bridge** and **Access Point**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Bridge and Access Point are the correct settings for extending your existing network onto wireless "media". the other options would create a second network.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:
Connection in this order: Router -> Switch -> PicoStation

Set the PicoStation in "Access Point" Mode.

If you do it this way the clients that connect the Access Point (PicoStation) will retrieve an DHCP Adresse from the Router. The wireless clients are in the same subnet as the clients connected to the switch.

If you want to divide the "normal" clients from the wireless clients you set the PicoStation to Router Mode.

Answer (score 0):

**Access Point** transmission media wireless, antena.
**Bridge** if transmission media like cable

the recommended option is router if you set DHCP
but in wireless i'm not sure about best option